# How do I recreate Ubercart's product attributes?

Tags: commerce, 9

While rebuilding an old D7 site with Ubercart into a new D9/Commerce installation, among other problems, I stumbled upon this one.

In Ubercart I can add as many product attributes as I want and make them show up in the product add to cart form as checkboxes with price adjustment, like this:

[image: product attributes in Ubercart]

No matter how much I tried playing around with Commerce product variations, I could not achieve this functionality.

I have added two product attributes in /admin/commerce/product-attributes, and there isn't an option for checkbox for any of them, just radio, select, rendered attribute. I have added a product variation type which has the two product attributes enabled, I added a product of the new variation type, and I added 3 variations with different SKUs for it - one for the plain product, one with the first attribute, one with the second attribute.

Yet it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Is this functionality even possible with Commerce?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade with Commerce Migrate Ubercart ( https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate_ubercart ) they automatically come and populate as an unattached product attribute if you use an empty database

They will show up as product attributes and you use them as product variation by creating a product type and using them as a variation

They will not show up attached the original product as it came from Ubercart.  You will need to create a product type and add the variation manually to each

See also https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/product-architecture/simple-product  and https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/products/configure-product-attributes